# Loss on LSTM is starting with a low value and decreasing slowly until it stops

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a bidirectional LSTM model that take words of a text as input, goes through an Embedding layer, a Bidirectional LSTM layer and finally though a Dense layer with 4 units and a softmax activation. The goal of this model is to predict if a word is an entity and what type of entity it is.

During training the model starts with a low validation and training loss (≈ 0.01) and decreases slowly until it stagnates. The texts in my dataset can vary in word length so I decided to pad the examples that had less than 2048 up to that value. The ones that had more than 2048 words (<1% of the dataset) were split into two or more texts and the last split was padded until it had 2048 words. I decided to use 2048 as the maximum size because I wanted to avoid splitting the examples and using 2048 would only split less than 1% of the data.

I'm using 4 recall functions (one for each class) as metrics and, although they are not giving awful results right at the start (the worst one is currently giving 75% for one of the classes), they do not improve over time. My guess is that this is a vanishing gradient problem since the sequence length is very large, but I'm not sure of this. I'll try again using inputs of size = 1024. I don't think the dataset size is the problem here since the training dataset that I'm using has around 500k examples, and the validation dataset has 50k. If there is anything more I need to add please let me know and I'll do it as soon as possible.

My model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 2048)]            0
_________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 2048, 300)         15145800
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 2048, 256)         439296
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 2048, 256)         0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 2048, 4)           1028
=================================================================
Total params: 15,586,124
Trainable params: 440,324
Non-trainable params: 15,145,800
```

Answer (score 0):

So yes, decreasing the input size by half did help me get better results. But that was not enough, I also had to add a new Bidirectional LSTM layer and double the number of units in both layers (256 to 512).